# How to eliminate the usage of a nullable bool

Tags: c#, boolean, nullable

I came up with this code, which I thought was rather clever (the requirement is that if the selected date is in the past, the TextBoxes should be readonly, otherwise (today's date or a future date) they should be editable):

```
bool? setReadOnly = null;

if (SelectedDateIsInThePast() && (!currentlyReadOnly)) {
    setReadOnly = true;
} else if (!SelectedDateIsInThePast() && (currentlyReadOnly)) {
    setReadOnly = false;
}
if (setReadOnlyToTrue.HasValue) {
    foreach (Control ctrl in tableLayoutPanelPlatypus.Controls) {
        if (ctrl is TextBox) {
            tb = (TextBox)ctrl;
            tb.ReadOnly = setReadOnlyToTrue.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

...but find that nullable bools are "data type non grata" among my compadres.

Is there a non-complicated way to do the same thing (only loop through the controls if the readonly value needs to be changed?). Of course, I could simply set them regardless of whether they needed to be set this way:

```
if (SelectedDateIsInThePast()) {
    setReadOnly = true;
} else {
    setReadOnly = false;
}
foreach (Control ctrl in tableLayoutPanelPlatypus.Controls) {
    if (ctrl is TextBox) {
        tb = (TextBox)ctrl;
        tb.ReadOnly = setReadOnly;
    }
}
```

...but I don't like to perform moot operations, if it's reasonably possible to avoid them.

Comment: I think your compadres should suck it up and accept a valid use of the data type.

Comment: I'm curious as to their objections to nullable bool.  Seems logical to me that if a bool doesn't have a value, null is an acceptable representation.

Comment: @James You're begging the question. A bool is either true or false; how can it _not_ have a value?

Comment: @AndresF: a bool only has two values, a nullable-bool has three (or rather, two values and a lack of either value).  There are cases where the bool does not apply in which case it is neither true nor false.

Comment: @James I understand the difference between `bool` and `bool?`. They are different types. Presumably, the OP's compadres reject `bool?`. Asking what type they propose to use to represent "a bool with no values" is not the right question -- they probably reject the use of any such type ;)

Comment: @AndresF: But they may reject it incorrectly, hence why I wish to know what they're concerns were.  Do they reject ALL use of Nullable<bool>, or just this use?  From the OPs question it sounded like the former and not the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Factor the loop into a method, and only call the method in the cases you set `setReadOnly`:

```
if (SelectedDateIsInThePast() && (!currentlyReadOnly)) {
    SetReadOnly(true);
} else if (!SelectedDateIsInThePast() && (currentlyReadOnly)) {
    SetReadOnly(false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `|=`, `&=`, and two non-nullable booleans to implement the same requirement:

```
bool forceReadOnly = SelectedDateIsInThePast() && (!currentlyReadOnly);
bool clearReadOnly = !(!SelectedDateIsInThePast() && (currentlyReadOnly));

foreach (Control ctrl in tableLayoutPanelPlatypus.Controls) {
    if (ctrl is TextBox) {
        tb = (TextBox)ctrl;
        tb.ReadOnly |= forceReadOnly;
        tb.ReadOnly &= clearReadOnly;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a nullable bool is fine... but another way would be:

```
public enum ControlState
{
    Unknown = 0,
    DateInPast,
    DateInFuture
}

....

var state = ControlState.Unknown;

if (SelectedDateIsInThePast() && (!currentlyReadOnly)) {
    state = ControlState.DateInPast;
} else if (!SelectedDateIsInThePast() && (currentlyReadOnly)) {
    state = ControlState.DateInFuture;
}
if (state != ControlState.Unknown) {
    foreach (Control ctrl in tableLayoutPanelPlatypus.Controls) {
        if (ctrl is TextBox) {
            tb = (TextBox)ctrl;
            tb.ReadOnly = setReadOnlyToTrue.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an enum with three separate, meaningful states ?

```
enum ShouldSetState
{
    No, 
    SetReadOnly,
    SetReadable
}
```

Then do

```
ShouldSetState setState = ShouldSetState.No;

if (SelectedDateIsInThePast() && (!currentlyReadOnly)) {
    setState = ShouldSetState.SetReadOnly;
} else if (!SelectedDateIsInThePast() && (currentlyReadOnly)) {
    setState = ShouldSetState.SetReadable;
}
if (setState != ShouldSetState.No) {
    foreach (Control ctrl in tableLayoutPanelPlatypus.Controls) {
        if (ctrl is TextBox) {
            tb = (TextBox)ctrl;
            tb.ReadOnly = setState == ShouldSetState.SetReadOnly;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be made more consise without using a nullable bool:

```
bool inThePast = SelectedDateIsInThePast();
if (currentlyReadOnly != inThePast )
{
    currentlyReadOnly = inThePast;
    foreach(var tb in tableLayoutPanelPlatypus.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        tb.ReadOnly = currentlyReadOnly;
}
```

Also, if you have to do a lot of these types of UI manipulations, you might consider [data binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8aebh9k.aspx).